# Object Orientated PHP, what's wrong with this implementation of OOPHP and how might it be improved?

Tags: php, object-oriented

I need some advice off the back of a question I posted on StackOverflow. I'm a procedural PHP programmer and I'm looking to make the move into object oriented PHP. I have started a small project that basically acts as a small CMS that allows me to separate my website content from the actual structure of the page. The code I am using to achieve this is:

```
<?php

class Connection extends Mysqli{

    public function __construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass, $mysqli_db) {
        parent::__construct($mysqli_host,$mysqli_user,$mysqli_pass,$mysqli_db);
        $this->throwConnectionExceptionOnConnectionError();     
    }

    private function throwConnectionExceptionOnConnectionError(){

        if(!$this->connect_error){
            echo "Database connection established<br/>";
        }else{
            //$message = sprintf('(%s) %s', $this->connect_errno, $this->connect_error);
            echo "Error connecting to the database."; 
            throw new DatabaseException($message);
        }
    }
}

class DatabaseException extends Exception
{
}

class Page{

    private $con; 

    public function __construct(Connection $con) {
        $this->con = $con;
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        }else{      
            $id = 1;
        }       
        $this->get_headers($id);
        $this->get_content($id);
        $this->get_footer($id);
    }

    private function get_headers($pageId){ 
        $retrieveHead = $this->con->prepare("SELECT headers FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
        $retrieveHead->bind_param('i',$pageId);
        $retrieveHead->execute();
        $retrieveHead->bind_result($header);
        $retrieveHead->fetch();
        $retrieveHead->close();
        echo $header;   
    }

    private function get_footer($pageId){ 
        $retrieveFooter = $this->con->prepare("SELECT footer FROM pages WHERE page_id=?");
        $retrieveFooter->bind_param('i',$pageId);
        $retrieveFooter->execute();
        $retrieveFooter->bind_result($footer);
        $retrieveFooter->fetch();
        $retrieveFooter->close();
        echo $footer;   
    }

    private function get_content($pageId){
        $retreiveContent = $this->con->prepare("SELECT template_id, section_title, i1, i2 FROM content WHERE page_id=? ORDER BY sequence DESC");
        $retreiveContent->bind_param('i',$pageId);
        $retreiveContent->execute();
        $retreiveContent->bind_result($template_id, $section_title, $i1, $i2);
        $retreiveContent->store_result();
        while ($retreiveContent->fetch()) {
        //Variables will be populated for this row.
        //Update the tags in the template.
        $template = $this->get_template($template_id);
        $template = str_replace('[i1]',$i1,$template);
        $template = str_replace('[i2]',$i2,$template);
        //$theTemplate is populated with content. Probably want to echo here
        echo $template;
        }
        $retreiveContent->free_result();    
        $retreiveContent->close();
    }

    private function get_template($template_id){
        $retreiveTemplate = $this->con->prepare("SELECT code FROM templates WHERE template_id=?");
        $retreiveTemplate->bind_param('i',$template_id);
        $retreiveTemplate->execute();
        $retreiveTemplate->bind_result($template);
        $retreiveTemplate->fetch();
        $retreiveTemplate->close();
        return $template;
    }

}
?>
```

I create a page object in my `index.php` file which is used to output the page by running the functions below in the order listed in the Page constructor. The comments I received on StackOverflow were along the lines of:

> This code violates numerous OOP principles. As a result of that, I hope that no newbies attempt to use this as a means of learning OOP, as they will be learning an invalid programming paradigm if they use what you have here as an example. Read up on the single responsibility principle and the other components of SOLID, and perhaps get a book on design patterns.

I've read up on these subjects and I remember a lot of the principals from Java in my first year of Uni (about 6 years ago now) but as far as I can see in my code I  am separating concerns as much as possible. It doesn't make sense to me to have the database connection as part of the page as it isn't really a property of the page whereas the headers and footers and content are. However, the page requires a database connection to function so I therefore have to pass a Connection object into the Page class to acheive the connectivity.

I've asked the authors of the comments numerous times to explain their reasoning behind such comments but all the keep doing is making statements saying this is bad code without providing examples as to why or what I might do to change it therefore I thought I'd ask this question here as I'll never learn if I'm not given a helping hand along the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object Orientated PHP, what's wrong with this setup?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21413/object-orientated-php-whats-wrong-with-this-setup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I see at first glance.

`Page` and `Connection` are extending `Mysqli`

Why is a Page a special Mysqli? (Page extends Mysqli)

Why is a Connection a special Mysqli? (Connection extends Mysqli)

A page can use a Mysqli to save stuff, but it *is not* a Mysqli.
Also the word Connection suggests it's a base-class of Mysqli (since a Connection can be a connection to a OracleDB, a TCP-Server etc.) but in your case Mysqli is the base for Connection.

The whole code implies you have no idea of OOP at all. Which is Okay, you can read some stuff about it, there is many outter there :)

Probably the most OOP programmers just see the code and don't know *where* to start improving it, because it just eludes them completly.

Comment: Sorry, that's actually old code from before I was passing the Connection object. Page shouldn't actually extend mysqli as you rightly suggest but once again I'm told I have no idea of OOP when most of this setup has been achieved using books and tutorials on the subject. Could you please elaborate..

Comment: Could you elaborate please. My implementation takes into account separation of concerns (e.g. the database object [Connection] is in charge of the connection to the database. The Page object [Page] is responsible for everything to do with the pages. I use inheritance correctly to ensure I am not duplicating code (My Connection class is a version of MySQLi with specified error handling).

Comment: Your `Connection` class adds nothing the `Mysqli` class did not already have. So why extend it? To add an extended exception, which also don't adds something new?

Comment: Okay so in your view I shouldn't have a Connection class. That's fine. This was suggested elsewhere to implement it in this way but instead of passing the Connection class in here I would pass in the base Mysqli class using the built in exception handling. Any other pointers (I really appreciate this) there is an absence of real world examples anywhere that explain these principles with useable code. All examples refer to animals or people but this isn't useful in understanding classes would come together to form a login system for example..

Comment: Yes, I know your problem very well :\ I've been there a few years ago, even studying computer science didn't help that much, since all examples in university where with animals or cars. Once I read a nice tutorial about MVC with PHP, which helped me alot. But I don't find it anymore.

Comment: probably something like this would help: http://r.je/mvc-in-php.html

Comment: Thanks @..K I'll take a look at this. I did OOP in Java years ago at Uni but as I am an expert in HTML and CSS I moved away from Java and learned procedural PHP instead. In my job I don't really code in PHP but I want to put a portfolio together and most comments online suggest that PHP should now be coded using OOP hence why I'm trying to learn it. However, I am still a fan of the procedural approach and don't understand why people call it inefficient. If functions are well commented and documented the a procedural application can be very easy to maintain so I may just stick to procedural..

Comment: as far as I know there is no empirical evidence that OOP is in any way better than procedural programming.

Comment: Exactly. However when applying for jobs (particularly in the UK) everyone seems to want OOPHP which is a shame because I'm a good programmer procedurally.